# What are the changes in the second edition of Cartoon Action Hour?

Tags: cartoon-action-hour

What are the rule changes between the [1st](http://www.zmangames.com/products/CAH/about.htm) and [2nd](http://spectrum-games.com/cahs2.aspx) editions of Cartoon Action Hour?  I am curious if there is significant new content in the second edition that makes it worth buying over the original.  The game appears to have changed publishers so I am uncertain if it is a complete re-write or a simple upgrade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the following link [From CAH:S1 to CAH:S2](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/lb_i.php?lb_id=12967727490B18520100&i_id=12968318730I58420300&p=11), explains the majority of them:

- Oomph and Stunt Points
- Character Points vs. Proof of Purchase Points
- Vehicles and Animal Companions
- etc...

There is also a length forum thread over at RPG Net, [CAH - S2 vs. S1](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?459680-CAH-S2-Cartoon-Action-Hour-Season-One-Vs-Season-Two).